# Android:SplashScreen Background image NOT CLEAR

Tags: android, splash-screen

I did an android application with splashscreen :

splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splashnine">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

where splashnine.png is very clear with 1333x2000 but the picture is not clear when tha app is launched.

Comment: can you show your sample image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should put different versions of this image to different `drawable` folders, such as `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, etc. If you just put the image to `drawable` folder, it's loaded as an `mdpi` image and then scaled up.

Second, when you set an image as a background, it's scaled up or down depending on the size of the view. It means that the quality of the image becomes worse because of resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ,since you use "fill_parent" with layout size parameters, image would be resized according to your device screen dimensions. try to change fill_parent to wrap_content or give DP values.